# Get last logon and email address from Exchange logs

Tags: powershell, exchange

I have created a PS script below which searches within our federated domain for a specific domain, and outputs the last login

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -Resultsize Unlimited |
    where {$_.emailAddresses -like "*@example.co.uk" } |
    Get-MailboxStatistics |
    Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,LastLogonTime |
    Export-CSV "C:\temp\O365-LastLogon-Info.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

So far it is only pulling the displayname and lastlogin and for some reason it doesn't pull the email address.

Comment: have you confirmed that `Get-MailboxStatistics` outputs an object with a property named `PrimarySmtpAddress`?

Comment: Get-MailboxStatistics does not have a property named PrimarySmtpAddress.  Get-Mailbox does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below PowerShell outputs the expected results in a csv file as you desire. Pipe only the `PrimarySmtpAddress` property value output of the `Get-Mailbox` command over to a `ForEach-Object` loop.

Use a variable to save `PrimarySmtpAddress` value in the loop and refer back to that with a calculated property naming the column and setting the value in the expression with the output of the `Select-Object` command.

### PowerShell

```
(Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | 
    ? { $_.emailAddresses -like "*@uspotus.us" }).PrimarySmtpAddress | % {
        $p = "";
        $p = $_;
        $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, @{N='PrimarySmtpAddress'; E={$p}}, LastLogonTime;
        } | Export-CSV "C:\temp\O365-LastLogon-Info.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8;
```

#### Output example

```
DisplayName   PrimarySmtpAddress LastLogonTime        
-----------   ------------------ -------------        
Barrack Obama bobama@uspotus.us  11/4/2021 11:18:11 PM
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Calculated_Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you
  > explicitly want to run the Where-Object command, run Where-object or
  > '`?`'
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

  > Standard Aliases for Select-Object: `select`

Comment: THANKS - this has worked a treat!!